# Stacking pseudo-class syntax?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have been searching the web for about an hour, however, I only seem to find "general" tutorials.

I have if I have a css code like

```
.foo {
   border-color: #ff000;
}

.foo:hover {
   border-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Can I make it into one class-like element? Below is a demonstration of an idea, I do not know if it is possible.

```
.foo {
   border-color: #ff0000;
   border-color-hover: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: No that is not possible.  You can't mix properties and selectors that way.  The first block of code is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to accomplish, you wouldn't use vanilla CSS. You could look into [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

LESS would let you do this:

```
foo { 
    border-color: #ff0000;
    &:hover { border-color: #0000ff; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between CSS and SASS compatibility and performance-wise? **EDIT: the link is self-explanatory**. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do that, you have to separate it into a `:hover` class like in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. And why should it be? Your first example works fine.

Comment: Simply to reduce the size of my css file and make it more tidy. ;)